# insert multiple values in one column with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query

```
$this->db->query("insert into
    booking (plot_id,booked_by_agent,id,totalamount)
    values ($a,$agent_id,$userID,$totalamount)
");
```

Where I want to insert 4 plot_id's in plot_id field for example 1,2,3,4...and booked_by_agent,id,totalamount are same for all 4 plot_id's. I want like this

```
plot_id   booked_by_agent   id      totalamount
1,2,3,4       23            12       100000
```

Comment: what is your $a output and datatype of plot_id  field?

Comment: $a output is 102 and datatype for plot_id int .Do i need to change datatype of field plot_id..

Comment: yes you have to change the datatype to text

Comment: If you want to store like this, change it into `varchar` or `text`

Comment: In what condition $a bring the value like `1,2,3,4`?

Comment: is 102  or $a ia array or string

Comment: Where does `1,2,3,4` come from?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you're gonna want to insert 4 rows, like:

```
plot_id   booked_by_agent   id      totalamount
------------------------------------------------
    1        23             12       100000
    2        23             12       100000
    3        23             12       100000
    4        23             12       100000
```

Your query will look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO booking (plot_id, booked_by_agent, id, totalamount) 
VALUES 
    (1, 23, 12, 100000), 
    (2, 23, 12, 100000),
    (3, 23, 12, 100000),
    (4, 23, 12, 100000);
```

Otherwise, as mentioned in the comments, you'll need to change the data type of `plot_id` to `varchar` or `text`. Although, it usually isn't a good idea to store strings of id's like that - but without knowing more about your system and what your needs are, it is hard to say.

Comment: you are right it's not a good idea to store string of id's like this..it will increase my problems in fetching data

Answer (score -1):

You can insert multiple rows via insert like this:

```
$this->db->query("insert into
    booking (plot_id,booked_by_agent,id,totalamount)
    values
        ('$a[0]','$agent_id',$userID,$totalamount),
        ('$a[1]','$agent_id',$userID,$totalamount),
        ('$a[2]','$agent_id',$userID,$totalamount),
        ('$a[3]','$agent_id',$userID,$totalamount)
");
```

You can generate the VALUES part with a foreach loop.

*Please change the array indexes to match your array!*

Answer (score -1):

First of all change `plot_id` column to `varchar` or `text` datatype and add all the values to a string like this

```
$plotid = $plot_id1.",".$plot_id2.",".$plot_id3.",".$plot_id4;
```

Now insert this `$plotid` in place of `$a`.
Now you query would be

```
$this->db->query("insert into
    booking (plot_id,booked_by_agent,id,totalamount)
    values ('$plotid','$agent_id',$userID,$totalamount)
");
```

Comment: If I insert plot_id's as string then whenever I want to fetch Plotno related to that plot_id's, how would I do that??

Comment: @KedarB In that case it becomes inaccessible. so you should consider reformatting your idea.Can i know for what reason you want to store like that ?

Answer (score -1):

First change your `plot_id` field datatype to `varchar`
Then if your `plot_id` is string like `102` then try

```
function stringToArray($s)
{
    $r = array();
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($s); $i++) 
         $r[$i] = $s[$i];
    return $r;
}
$a = "102";
$arr = stringToArray($a);
$a = implode(',', $arr);
$this->db->query("insert into booking (plot_id,booked_by_agent,id,totalamount) values ('$a','$agent_id',$userID,$totalamount)");
```

else plot_id is coming one by one then try to separate it with comma like :-

```
$a = $plot_id1.",".$plot_id2.",".$plot_id3.",".$plot_id4;
$this->db->query("insert into booking (plot_id,booked_by_agent,id,totalamount) values ('$a','$agent_id',$userID,$totalamount)");
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing is that you need to assign varchar type to you plot_id column.
Then you can do this.

Assuming plot ids are coming from array.

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$a = implode(',',$a);
$this->db->query("insert into
     booking (plot_id,booked_by_agent,id,totalamount)
    values ('$a',$agent_id,$userID,$totalamount)
");
```

Answer (score -1):

1: you can use while loop like this

`$a = 1;
while ($a<=4){
$this->db->query("insert into
    booking (plot_id,booked_by_agent,id,totalamount)
    values ($a,$agent_id,$userID,$totalamount)
");
$a++;
}`

2: Or you can check from database if the `agent id` with the same `user id` is already present in the database than just add the same with new id.